# How to make Live Charts DataTooltip only show current hover?

Tags: c#, winforms, livecharts

I have a pie chart using Live Charts  in a winform and I've tried using the code in the [documentation](https://lvcharts.net/App/examples/v1/wf/Tooltips%20and%20Legends) to change the tool tip to just the current hover:

```
pieChart1.DataTooltip.SelectionMode = LiveCharts.TooltipSelectionMode.OnlySender;
```

However I get the following error: Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State

```
'UserControl' does not contain a definition for 'SelectionMode' and no accessible extension method 'SelectionMode' accepting a first argument of type 'UserControl' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I am not sure what I am missing? The code below is what I am using to draw the piechart.

```
Func<ChartPoint, string> labelPoint = chartPoint =>
            string.Format("${0:n}", chartPoint.Y, chartPoint.Participation);

        SeriesCollection series = new SeriesCollection();
        //reads in a data table and creates a pie series for each data row
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            PieSeries ps = new PieSeries
            {
                Title = dr["Name"].ToString(),
                Values = new ChartValues<double> {
                            double.Parse(dr["Budget Amount"].ToString())},
                DataLabels = true,
                LabelPoint = labelPoint

            };

            series.Add(ps);
        }

        pieChart1.Series = series;          
        pieChart1.LegendLocation = LegendLocation.Bottom;
        pieChart1.DataTooltip.SelectionMode = LiveCharts.TooltipSelectionMode.OnlySender;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DataTooltip can be any WPF UserControl. So to change the SelectionMode you need to cast it to a `DefaultTooltip`.

```
var tooltip = (LiveCharts.DefaultTooltip) pieChart1.DataTooltip
tooltip.SelectionMode = LiveCharts.TooltipSelectionMode.OnlySender
```

Comment: This is in a winform so I am not sure how to do what you are saying.

Comment: @Jacob I added some code, to make my answer clearer.

Comment: Thank you! Made a lot more sense.

Comment: In windows form, I was getting error on "LiveCharts.DefaultToolTip". Following code worked fine for me 

                var tooltip = (DefaultTooltip)PieChartPriorityDisplay.DataTooltip;
                tooltip.SelectionMode = TooltipSelectionMode.OnlySender;